# Insert statement in procedure with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well I have this Procedure with this insert statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_job
AS
INSERT INTO jobs(job_id, job_title) VALUES('IT_DBA', 'Database Administrator');
GO;
```

Instead of hardcoding the values I'd like to use parameters so every time I call this procedure I should be able to insert new values.

Comment: This is not PL/SQL code, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_job (
    @job_id varchar(255),
    @job_title varchar(255)
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO jobs(job_id, job_title)
        VALUES(@job_id, @job_title);
END;
```

Of course, you haven't specified the types of the columns, so I just made up the `varchar(255)` as a reasonable type.

Comment: The tables with the columns already exist. Do I have to ad the varchar(255) then too

Comment: @sqlhelper10 . . . Those are parameters to the stored procedure.  They should ideally have the same type as the columns in the table.

Comment: I get this error then 
Error (2,5): PLS-00103: Found the symbol "@" when one of the following was expected: <an identifier> <a double- quoted delimited-identifier> current delete exists prior

Comment: @sqlhelper10 . . . If you are using Oracle, then the code in your question won't work at all.

Comment: This is standard ANSI SQL and should work on any DBMS

It definitely works for:

Oracle
MS SQL Server
MySQL
Postgres
SQLite v3
Teradata
DB2
Sybase
Vertica
HSQLDB
H2
AWS RedShift
SAP HANA

Comment: @sinfella . . . `GO` is standard SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_statement(parameter_name VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db_table VALUES (default, parameter_name);
END;
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_job]

@job_id VarChar (50),
@job_Title VarChar (50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[jobs]
  ([job_id] 
 , job_title)
 VALUES
(@job_id, @job_title)
END;
```